# Got error on Archive : framework not found AppAuth

Tags: ios, xcode, package

Here is the error I get on Archive:

[image: Here is the error I get on Archive]

I am using packages only. No pods.
Has Anybody facing or solved this error?

ld: framework not found AppAuth
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

The project runs on device, I get this only on Archive.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am facing the same error but unable to fine the solution. @zidniryi After installing the GoogleSign-iOS through package manger Xcode start giving this error. I have tried both Pod and package manager but it still coming. 
I have spent continues 4 days on this issue but unable to find the solution ??

Answer (score 0):

I realised that I have to use pods, because somehow Google sign in package and Facebook package conflicted.
So with pods now it's working ok.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and it turned out it was due to using SwiftPM and cocoapods in parallel.

I then removed cocoapods from my project and the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by using this workaround.

in `APPNAME/ios/App/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-App/Pods-App-frameworks.sh` replaced `source="$(readlink "${source}")"`  with `source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"`

Reset the `package caches` and run `pod updated` after making these changes.

Answer (score 0):

I got build failed with "AppAuth not found" message after install a newer version of xcode. I fixed the issue by the following steps:

1. Navigate to the project folder, delete the pod folder, Podfile.lock file and the your-project.xcworkspace
2. Switch to the terminal window of macos, cd to the project directory path
3. execute the command:

   ```
   pad update
   ```
4. Open the project by Xcode, rebuild and success.